# how to let the DataPager know the number of total records in the DataSource in custom paging?

Tags: listview, custompaging

The default paging mechanism needs to have the entire contents of the query that's to be paged through each time the ListView is rendered so that it can correctly determine how many pages the data can be broken up into.

Essentially, it needs to know how many total records we're paging through.

So, when employing custom paging we will be returning only those records that need to be displayed on the current page of data being viewed; however, we will also need to let the DataPager know the number of total records in the DataSource that the query being paged through consists of.

How do we do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

VirtualItemCount, which is supposedly only supported in the older control's like the DataGrid. But what about ListView?